# Need help verifying my MySQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

Somewhat new to SQL. Cannot seem to figure out what i'm doing wrong!!

```
UPDATE mileagetable 
SET EndMileage= `4599`, 
    EndTime= `9 : 12 AM` 
WHERE mileagetable.id= 26
```

Basically i have a db called lets say db83838383
and a table in that db called mileagetable
And 30 records identified by the primary key " id "
I'm just trying to open a currently existent record "26" and fill in two empty feilds.

I cannot seem to get my query to work? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you shouldn't need backticks for your integer or your time.  those look like strings so you should just use apostrophe.

Comment: single  `' '` u should be using instead of ``

Comment: Change the backticks (``) to normal quotes (`'`).
Also, I don't know what the type of `EndTime` is but if it is a `TIMESTAMP` o r something like that, it may not like `9 : 12 AM`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ticks are for identifiers. Quotes are for string values:

```
UPDATE mileagetable 
SET EndMileage= `4599`, 
    EndTime= `9 : 12 AM` 
WHERE mileagetable.id= 26
```

should be

```
UPDATE mileagetable 
SET EndMileage= '4599', 
    EndTime= '9 : 12 AM' 
WHERE mileagetable.id= 26
```